# Lwjgl on android

Tags: android, lwjgl3

How do I compile a lwjgl program written in java with openGL and glfw to run on android.
I Should use openGL es for android..But how to create context for gles  and input for touch screen.

Update:

In general how do I port openGL game written in java to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use LWJGL on android because it uses normal OpenGL, while android only supports OpenGL ES. You need to rewrite your app with the one given by the android SDK.

Although there is a support for normal GLES, you can't get inputs like touches, swipes, sensors, erc.

Comment: But lwjgl comes with openGL es binding...

Comment: @yashwanth see edit

Comment: Whether programming for desktop with Gles is a good idea or not?

Comment: @yash Why would you use GLES if you can use the normal one?

Comment: Sorry.I got too excited...But what if i call openGL Es compliant function in openGL on android...Will it work...coz they said es is a stripped down version..so the implementation should not change know

Comment: @yash I don't think you can connect it with a glSurfaceView.

Comment: Oh...lemme check it later